# How to catch assert() in WM_PAINT handler?

Tags: c++, winapi, game-development

I have MSVC 2019, vc142 x64, SDK 10.0.18362.0, WINAPI game project, JIT debugging is enabled, `_DEBUG` is defined. I use `assert()` from standard lib `#include <cassert>`. `assert(expr)` call expands to `_wassert`. If test code `assert(false)` is placed wherever excluding `WM_PAINT` handler, a window with Abort/Retry/Ignore options is shown and it's intended behavior.

But in case I have `assert(false)` in `case WM_PAINT`, assert window is not being shown. Program just aborts and writes to stderr. Problem is that a lot of game logic is called from `WM_PAINT`'s handler (e.g. `Core::Update(dt)`) and I cannot catch any assert produced by my code.

WndProc code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        assert(false);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program spams this message and does not stop:

```
Program: ...t\source\repos\Test3\x64\Debug\WindowsProject1.exe
File: C:\Users\b2soft\source\repos\Test3\...\Windows...ct1.cpp
Line: 149

Expression: false

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts

(Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)Assertion failed!
```

I want to have the same debug window with Abort/Retry/Ignore options even if `assert()` is fired from `WM_PAINT`

Comment: You really should be using `OutputDebugString` for these types of messages, or even `DebugBreak`, not `assert()`.  Pulling the rug out from under the WM_PAINT handler like this by issuing `assert()` calls is not wise.

Comment: assert always write to the debugger if there's one. In this case, since it's a Windows app, it also tries to use the MessageBox API but this fails because your WM_PAINT implementation is broken. You can try to replace your assert(false) call by MessageBox(something) and you will see it doesn't work either (on My PC GetLastError on MessageBox is ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS for some internal Windows reason). The solution is to simply add the standard BeginPaint and EndPaint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to be careful when handling the `WM_PAINT` message. Windows manager constantly monitors which parts of the screen need to be redrawn and adds this information to window's update region. When the `GetMessage` or the `PeekMessage` is called and there is no message with higher priority, the `WM_PAINT` message is generated for windows with nonempty update region.

The `BeginPaint` prepares window's device context using update region to limit painting area. After this update region is cleared, so the window can collect new areas for painting even before it starts drawing current ones.

If we omit the `BeginPaint` call, the update region is not cleared (unles we use alternative solutions as for example `ValidateRect`) and `WM_PAINT` is always ready to be dispatched. This leads to endless stream of `WM_PAINT` messages with high processor usage. Remember that `DefWindowProc` handles the `WM_PAINT` internally so these problems manifests only when you explicitly intercept `WM_PAINT` messages.

Using the `asert` in `WM_PAINT` handler without or before the `BeginPaint` call, leads to unwanted interaction between message boxes and `WM_PAINT` messages. Depending on settings `assert` could display message box which starts new (nested) message loop. When message box build by `assert` is to be shown `WM_PAINT` for original window is generated again. This leads to next nested loop again and again. After 32 nested calls `MessageBox` fails and program is aborted (by call to `abort` function).

**Putting `BeginPaint` (or any alternative which clears update region) before `assert` stops recursive loop nesting (at least until next `WM_PAINT` is dispatched) and `assert` can display message box correctly.**

So if you want to use `assert` in `WM_PAINT` handler, put it after `BeginPaint` or `ValidateRect(hWnd, NULL)`.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // assert here could lead to abort

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        // assert here could lead to abort

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // Update region cleared, no WM_PAINT will be generated
        // until some event creates new dirty area

        // assert here have chance to be handled properly
        assert(false);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // assert here have chance to be handled properly
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    // assert here have chance to be handled properly

    return 0;
}
```

Remember this is based on observed behavior not on any specific documentation, so you could get different results depending on settings, runtime version and even debugger being attached or not.

Tests done on Windows 10 with VC2017 x86 Debug build ucrt 10.0.17763.0

Personally I didn't know about this limitation and it looks somewhat bad. Especially for eventual asserts placed at a top of the window procedure. Fortunately attached debugger at least displays errors in the output window and I never run debug builds without debugger attached.

Comment: *"If we omit the `BeginPaint` call, the update region have no chance to be cleared"* - That's not completely accurate. There is [ValidateRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-validaterect), for example. *"I didn't know about this limitation and it looks somewhat bad"* - The alternative would be worse: A stack overflow exception with not helpful diagnostic output.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use the [`BeginPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint) and [`EndPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-endpaint) functions, the system will continuously send [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) messages when it is idle, which will cause some abnormal situations.

So only need to modify the code as follows:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        HDC hdc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        RECT rect;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        assert(false);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: It is common for games to continuously redraw the scene, and not rely on the system to handle invalidation. While correct in general, this answer is an answer to a different question, not this one. I downvoted, because it doesn't make any attempt to actually explain, what the issue is. It's no more useful than your average *"Try this: <lots of code>"* answer.

Comment: Accoding to the [The WM_PAINT Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/the-wm-paint-message):BeginPaint sets the update region of a window to NULL. This clears the region, preventing it from generating subsequent WM_PAINT messages. If an application processes a WM_PAINT message but does not call BeginPaint or otherwise clear the update region, the application continues to receive WM_PAINT messages as long as the region is not empty. In all cases, an application must clear the update region before returning from the WM_PAINT message.

Comment: That documentation is written with desktop application developers in mind. For desktop applications it makes sense to validate the invalid area by calling `BeginPaint`. For a system that doesn't rely on the system to manage invalidated window regions, there is no requirement for an application to handle `WM_PAINT` in this way. For games in particular, `WM_PAINT` is often used like a timer, that continuously fires, with the added bonus of getting paused, when the window is minimized.

Comment: In most cases omitting `BeginPaint` call results in endless stream of `WM_PAINT` messages, but `assert` tries to display `MessageBox` which starts new (nested) message loop, dispatches `WM_PAINT`, calls `assert` again, starts new message loop etc. After 32 nested calls `abort` is called ad program exists. Putting `BeginPaint` before `assert` stops loop nesting (at least until next `WM_PAINT` is dispatched) and `assert` can display message box correctly.

Comment: @dan That shouldn't be a comment. That's a genuine answer, that explains what causes the observed behavior, and how/why the proposed solution addresses it.

Comment: @IInspectable that is actually what I have, WM_PAINT is like a Timer, where global Update/Render funcs are called. So I don't need BeginPaint/EndPaint at all and spam WM_PAINT is OK for me